# How to make an method change the root view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

My app is structured like this:

```
- Window
 - Navigation controller
   - Table view
    - Button (in one of the rows)
 - Tab bar controller
  - tab..
  - tab..
  - tab..
```

(The tab bar controller isn't added as a sub view so it can't be seen)

How would you make the button able to manipulate the Navigation controller and tab bar controller objects?

Comment: what would you like to do exactly?

Comment: The navigation controller is showing at the moment (its a login screen). I'd like to hide it and add the Tab bar controller as a subview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could have them as properties in your `AppDelegate` like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

And than in your table view you can get a pointer to them like this:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [(YourAppDelegateClass *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] navigationController];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [(YourAppDelegateClass *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] tabBarController];
```

After this you can have your button do whatever you want to them. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not accurate. Both `UITabbarController` and `UINavigationController` are **controllers of multiple view controllers**. So, in your structure, you should add a `UITableViewController` between "Navigation controller" and "Table view".

According to Apple's View Controller Programming Guide for iOS, you can assign both view controllers or tab bar controllers to the items to be controlled by a tab bar controller.

Thus, you could have this structure:

```
- Window
  - Tabbar Controller
    -Navigation Controller
      - Table View Controller
        - Table view
          - Button
    - tab (another View Controller)
    - tab
    - etc.
```

You can hide the `UITabbar` when the table view is visible.

You could then access everything the way you would expect: from the `UITableViewController` it would work with `self.navigationController`, or `self.tabbarController`.

Answer (score 0):

Given this description of what you would like to do:

> The navigation controller is showing at the moment (its a login screen). I'd like to hide it and add the Tab bar controller as a subview

I think that you do not really need that the button has got references to the navigation controller and to the tab bar.

You can define a method in your app delegate that you can access directly from the button, like this:

```
[[(MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate] doSwapNavAndTabBar];
```

the app delegate is the most natural point to do this, since it is in a way "responsible" for the `window` object where you want to do the swap.

If the tab bar that you want to show depends in some way from the button, then I would suggest to pass the button reference as an argument to that method:

```
[[(MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate] doSwapNavAndTabBar:button];
```

as it is usually done to manage events generated through controls. The app delegate can then ask the button for the information necessary to decide on which tab bar to show or how to initialize it.